# Three different second-order discretizations for the mixed derivative $u_{xy}$

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

I need to derive three discretizations, and present them as stencils. I already found one:

$\frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}u_{i+1,j}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}u_{i-1,j}}{2h}$

$\frac{u_{i+1,j+1}-u_{i+1,j-1}-u_{i-1,j+1}+u_{i+1,j+1}}{4h^2}$

so the stencil is:$\frac{1}{4h^2}\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0&1 \\  0&0&0  \\ 1&0&-1\\  \end{bmatrix}$.

Can someone help me on how to derive the two?

Comment: There are many different ones you can use. Is there a form you are looking for?

Comment: yes @PiotrBenedysiuk, they need be of the form $\frac{1}{4h^2}\begin{bmatrix} a2 & a1&0 \\  a1&a3&0a1 \\ 0&a1&a2\\  \end{bmatrix}$ and $\frac{1}{4h^2}\begin{bmatrix} 0& a1&a2 \\  a1&a3&a1  \\ a2&a1&0\\  \end{bmatrix}$, although im not sure if $\frac{1}{4h^2}$ is the case because I calculated one version with only $\frac{1}{h^2}$

Answer (score 0):

Some notation first: $u_{i,j}$ denotes the function at place $(i,j)$. The superscript denotes the derivatives ie $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} u = u^x$

We will first Taylor expand all the terms in the stencil around $u_{i,j}$.

$$u_{i,j} = u_{i,j} \\
u_{i \pm1, j} = u_{i,j} + (\pm h)u_{i,j}^x + \frac{h^2}{2}u_{i,j}^{xx} \\
u_{i, j \pm 1} = u_{i,j} + (\pm h)u_{i,j}^y + \frac{h^2}{2} u_{i,j}^{yy}\\
u_{i \pm1, j \pm 1} = u_{i,j} + (\pm h)u_{i,j}^y + (\pm h)u_{i,j}^x + \frac{h^2}{2}(u_{i,j}^{xx} + (\pm)(\pm)2 u_{i,j}^{xy} + u_{i,j}^{yy})$$

Where, the sign in front of $u_{i,j}^{xy}$ depends both on $\pm$ in $i$ and in $j$.

Now, somewhat bruteforce-ish, we will approximate $u_{i,j}^{xy}$ by the sum of terms above, with weights given by the stencil in question.

$u_{i,j}^{xy} \approx \frac{1}{h^2}\big(a_1 u_{i,j} + a_2 (u_{i-1,j}+u_{i+1,j}+u_{i,j-1}+u_{i,j+1}) + a_3 (u_{i-1,j+1}+u_{i+1,j-1})\big)$

Rewriting (plugging in the expressions of Taylor expansion gives, and rearranging the equation in terms of different derivatives)

$$
a_1 + 4a_2 + 2a_3 = 0 \text{    eliminating } u_{i,j} \\
2a_2 + 2a_3 = 0 \text{    eliminating } u_{i,j}^{xx} \\
2a_2 + 2a_3 = 0 \text{    eliminating } u_{i,j}^{yy} \\
-a_3 = 1 \text{    preserving } u_{i,j}^{xy} \\
$$

Observe that in our case $u_{i,j}^{x}$ term is eliminated for all values of $a_2, a_3$ the same for $u_{i,j}^{y}$.

Solving the equations gives:
$a_3 = -1, a_2 = 1, a_1 = -2$ and thus the stencil.

The second form can be done in similar fashion - the last equation will now read $a_3 =1$.

Likewise, the last stencil can be done as well by writing out the equation and grouping the terms by derivatives.

Comment: In the first line, shouldn't it be $\frac{1}{h^2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2h}$? Anyway I think I understand it now, you can make whatever you want, using different backward or forward or central methods.

Comment: No, in the first line I'm only taking a derivative with respect to $y$ once, hence $h$ to the power of $1$. You can reassure yourself that this is indeed the derivative with respect to $y$ be expanding $u$ as Taylor series around $u_{i,j}$.

Comment: but you take the derivative with the central difference method? or what method you use? because it looks alot like the second derivative central method.

Comment: Oh I see you are right. My method indeed does not work. I'll delete edit when its fixed.

Comment: @Eran Fixed now :)